# Generalized tuple reduce

Tags: haskell

How can I write function that reduce n-tuple to (n-m)-tuple?

For example, I have `(a, b, c, d, e)` and want to get `(a, b, c)`
which is used like

```
let ntup  = (1, "a", "b", 5, "c")
    nmtup = reduce ntup 3
```

Comment: There is no vanilla Haskell way. You need some fancy type manipulation to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears there are some solutions to similar problems (e.g., [Manipulating "arbitrary" tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436366/manipulating-arbitrary-tuples)), but I'd strongly advise you to consider changing data types instead because tuples are not meant to be used in a context such as this one. Tuples are not meant to somehow iterate on the elements, but rather to pattern match against (a fixed number of) them.
An alternative could be an [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) data type, as mentioned in one of the answers to the question I linked you.

Comment: In fact, a point could be made that only 2-tuples should ever be used at all and everything bigger should be either a record or a list (with a variant type or heterogeneous).

Comment: Could you point me to some reference explaining better this statement, please? It sounds interesting! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's just that when you stay with pairs, all you need to build concise pipelines etc. is `fst`, `snd` and the arrow combinators `first`, `second`, `&&&` and `***`. When you allow for bigger tuples, the number of helpers grows quadratically (if not exponentially), or else you need polymorphic signatures, which overcomplicate type inference. You can use lenses (`_1`, `_2`), but that quickly becomes confusing. Named record fields are much clearer, no matter if you use lenses or not. _If_ you use bigger tuples, then `((a,b),c)` actually tends to be more convenient than `(a,b,c)`!

Comment: Thanks! Moved to HList, I wanted to make conversion without much additional work (adding new library), but end up there anyway